# Why is a saved Exchange password not being used?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, passwords

I'm using Outlook 2007 with two different Exchange accounts and neither account saves my login credentials.  Every time I start Outlook, I have to enter my password again, regardless of whether I check "Remember my password".  I don't have any problems with my IMAP accounts.

Is there a way around this, or is this a setting on Exchange Server that prohibits using saved credentials?

I've tried using the [instructions on this page](http://redwax.wordpress.com/2007/04/24/outlook-remote-access-features-cant-save-a-password-for-automatic-logon-exchange-role-based-server-security-solution/) but it did not work.

I use one server exclusively through Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTPS), but the other server I use both locally and via Outlook Anywhere, and I'm only prompted for credentials when using the latter method.

Comment: Since you administer an exchange server, your best bet for a good answer is serverfault.com

Comment: I thought that might be good second choice; I posted here because there's something the client COULD do to use saved passwords because my iPhone and other people's Windows Mobile phones don't ask for passwords each time. I just don't know if Outlook exposes this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting can be and probably is set in Exchange. There's nothing you can do about it.

Since you have admin access to one of the servers: If you are using RPC over HTTP(S) you can follow the steps here for Exchange 2003 http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;820281

Comment: I'm the administrator of one of the Exchange servers, so yes, there is something I can do about it =)

Comment: Are you using RPC over HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: And also, is your Exchange domain the same as your production domain, or are they separate?

Comment: RPC over HTTPS, and each Exchange server is on their respective production domains. I edited my question with a step I've tried.

Comment: A-ha, I had to follow these instructions AND enable NTLM authentication on the server (Server Properties -> Client Access -> (server) Properties -> Outlook Anywhere.  Thanks!